# XUnit Mock not throwing exception like I would expect

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have the following test that uses a mock of a class. When I try to throw an exception it never actually throws the exception. It goes on as if the method is actually being called and I am unsure why.

Here is the test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task ReadResultSetShouldRetry()
{
    // Arrange
    _cosmosUtilWrapper.Setup(x => x.ReadCosmosResultSet<CosmosRepositoryTests>(It.IsAny<FeedIterator>(), It.IsAny<ILogger>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Throws(new Exception("It broke"));

    var cosmosReadPolicy = new CosmosReadPolicy();

    // Act
    await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(async () => await CosmosRepository.ReadCosmosResultSetWithRetry<CosmosRepositoryTests>(_mockFeedIterator.Object, _logger, cosmosReadPolicy, CancellationToken.None));
    // Assert
    _cosmosUtilWrapper.Verify(x => x.ReadCosmosResultSet<CosmosRepositoryTests>(_mockFeedIterator.Object, _logger, default));
}
```

Here is the method that it is calling and I have it wrapped in a retry policy:

```
public static async Task<List<T>> ReadCosmosResultSetWithRetry<T>(
    FeedIterator resultSet,
    ILogger logger,
    CosmosReadPolicy cosmosReadPolicy,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    where T : class
{
    CosmosUtilWrapper utilWrapper = new CosmosUtilWrapper();

    var readCosmosResultSet = await cosmosReadPolicy.GetPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await utilWrapper.ReadCosmosResultSet<T>(resultSet, logger, cancellationToken));

    return readCosmosResultSet;
}
```

Here is the CosmosUtilWrapper and below is the actual Cosmos Util class:

```
public class CosmosUtilWrapper
{
    public virtual async Task<List<T>> ReadCosmosResultSet<T>(
        FeedIterator resultSet,
        ILogger logger,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        where T : class
    {
        return await CosmosUtil.ReadCosmosResultSet<T>(resultSet, logger, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Here is the actual static Util method that is being returned in the above class. Had to go about it this way since this class is a static class and unit testing those are not very fun.

```
public static async Task<List<T>> ReadCosmosResultSet<T>(
    FeedIterator resultSet,
    ILogger logger,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    where T : class
{
    var foundDocuments = new List<T>();
    while (resultSet.HasMoreResults)
    {
        using ResponseMessage responseMessage = await resultSet.ReadNextAsync(cancellationToken);
        if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            using StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseMessage.Content);
            using JsonTextReader textReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader);
            foundDocuments.AddRange((await JObject.LoadAsync(textReader, cancellationToken)).GetValue("Documents").ToObject<List<T>>());
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"Unable to read cosmos result set. Status code: {responseMessage.StatusCode}");
        }
    }

    return foundDocuments;
}
```

Finally, Here is the message I get when running the tests

```
  Message: 
    Assert.Throws() Failure
    Expected: typeof(System.Exception)
    Actual:   (No exception was thrown)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the mockup object `_cosmosUtilWrapper` in `ReadResultSetShouldRetry()` is never used in `Task<List<T>> ReadCosmosResultSetWithRetry<T>`.

In methode `Task<List<T>> ReadCosmosResultSetWithRetry<T>` you initialize a new object `CosmosUtilWrapper utilWrapper = new CosmosUtilWrapper();`. So, this object is not the same as the object above.

You can get the object from the mockup object with the following code: `_cosmosUtilWrapper.Object`. Pass this object in the function or in the constructor of the class when you remove the static from the methode.

For example:

```
public static async Task<List<T>> ReadCosmosResultSetWithRetry<T>(
    FeedIterator resultSet,
    ILogger logger,
    CosmosReadPolicy cosmosReadPolicy,
    CosmosUtilWrapper utilWrapper,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    where T : class
{
    var readCosmosResultSet = await cosmosReadPolicy.GetPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await utilWrapper.ReadCosmosResultSet<T>(resultSet, logger, cancellationToken));

    return readCosmosResultSet;
}
```

For example Test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task ReadResultSetShouldRetry()
{
    // Arrange
    _cosmosUtilWrapper.Setup(x => x.ReadCosmosResultSet<CosmosRepositoryTests>(It.IsAny<FeedIterator>(), It.IsAny<ILogger>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Throws(new Exception("It broke"));

    var cosmosReadPolicy = new CosmosReadPolicy();
    var utilWrapper = _cosmosUtilWrapper.Object;

    // Act
    await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(async () => await CosmosRepository.ReadCosmosResultSetWithRetry<CosmosRepositoryTests>(_mockFeedIterator.Object, _logger, cosmosReadPolicy, utilWrapper, CancellationToken.None));
    // Assert
    _cosmosUtilWrapper.Verify(x => x.ReadCosmosResultSet<CosmosRepositoryTests>(_mockFeedIterator.Object, _logger, default));
}
```